# Why is this model rendering with dark faces in cycles render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

rendered screenshot

[image]

editor view

[image]

[image]

Notice the dark faces. Even though it's not in shadow from anywhere and all normals are correctly facing as far as i can tell. I have also tried different/fresh material but that doesn't seem to affect this issue.

---

edit: replies to the comments (dunno how else to answer them) :

1. the link is invalid. goes to a 404 page.

2. the lighting setup is a the default blender sun lamp. 

3. the mesh is not distorted at all. its appearance is due to the weird rendering issue.

4. thanks for the correct link. this awesome service should be integrated directly into this forum imo.


i see that this question is a duplicate, so moderators feel free to delete if required. I did search for an answer here before posting, guess I was using wrong keywords.

Comment: When you go into cycles the lamp doesn't work the same way. Try changing the lighting by deleting the lamp and adding a new one. I'm a new user to blender also so I can't really say which is best.

Comment: please, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/to share .blend files  (free and permanent), then edit you question and paste the provided link.

Comment: please show the lighting setup in the scene and material setup for this object... not enough info, imho.

Comment: The mesh is so distorted that even with good lighting it will be hard to go away from light artifacts.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. didn't have any effect. the scene is just darker now. :(

Comment: Here is the corrected link to the sharing site for this stackexchange http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @avi1708  no need to delete the question. Duplicates are a good thing, they might help others with the same issues find the information they need. Welcome to the site. Feel free to use the search box at the top and keep on asking new questions.

Comment: @cetagon :D thanks. this forum is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Add modifier "Subdivision Surface"

2 Go in edit mode, press "Shift E" (Edge Crease) drag the mouse

2 or in Edit Mode press N Side Panel > Transform > Mean Crease to 1.0

Comment: (what sorcery was this? o.O) it fixed the issue, so i'm marking your answer as correct. but i think more proper solution/explanation is given in the duplicate post marked by cetagon.

Comment: Yes I agree, about the "sorcery" Edge Crease + Subdivion Surface and/or Edge Split this is a nice  technique for hard surface modelling, and also it makes the normals perfect.